# Auto white spaces are added

Tags: ios, uitableview

Hello i have UItableview but during each row at space is added automatically.For example
abc
 aaa
  vvv
    ttt
bbb
then last entry is again from beginning.Any help thx in advance!

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    if(tableView == tableAttendeeList)
    {
    static    NSString *cellName=@"AttendeeCell";

        UITableViewCell *tvc = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellName];
        NSLog(@"%@",tvc.textLabel.text);
        NSLog(@"%i",indexPath.row);
        if (tvc == nil) {
            tvc=[[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellName]autorelease];
            HMAttendee* attdee = [[HMMainManager getSharedInstance].currentMeeting.arrMeetingUsers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  
            NSLog(@"%@",attdee.strName);

            tvc.textLabel.text = attdee.strName;

        return tvc;    
        }
        HMAttendee* attdee = [[HMMainManager getSharedInstance].currentMeeting.arrMeetingUsers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  
        tvc.textLabel.text=attdee.strName;
        return tvc;

    }//end if
```

Comment: please ignore the example it is wrongly printed here

Answer (score 0):

k i found the solution. thx any ways i just change indentation lvl

```
tvc.indentationLevel = 0;
tvc.indentationWidth = 0;
```